# System Shell Scripts Can't Find my Command in PATH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, root

I put a custom command (shell script) in `/usr/local/scripts/`.

In order to see commands from `/usr/local/scripts`, I set the PATH using the following methods:

1. `sudo visudo`

   ```
   Defaults  secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/scripts"
   ```
2. `sudo nano /etc/profile`

   PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/scripts"
   export PATH
3. `sudo nano /etc/login.defs`

   ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/scripts
   ENV_PATH        PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/scripts
4. `sudo nano /root/.bashrc`

   PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/scripts"
   export PATH
5. `sudo nano /etc/environment`

   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/scripts"

And this works in most cases, but...

I have two script which, in their code, calls a script from `/usr/local/scripts/`,  and it can't find my script!

The first is `/etc/network/if-up.d/sendip`, which is run as root when the networking stack is initialized.

And the second is `/usr/local/scripts/notif-login` which is run as root from `pam` by `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session optional pam_exec.so /usr/local/scripts/notif-login
```

If I run both script from my terminal shell, another user, with sudo, without sudo, after su, or login with root, it works properly. But when it is runner by the system (first when networking initialized, and the second via SSH) both failed to run scripts from `/usr/local/scripts`.

Is there another place where I have to set the path?

Comment: Why don't you just use the full path?

Comment: Because I want to know why don't work without full path if their directory is in the path

Answer (score 1):

Bash/sh will not read `/etc/profile` for "non-interactive shells", such as the shells from which the scripts you mention run. I'm not sure which distribution you're using, but you should just be able to add it to `/etc/environment`'s `PATH` definition. Ob Ubuntu, for example:

Change:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

To:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/scripts"
```

**Edit**

This should work under Raspbian; it does under Debian. If it doesn't, you might need to just modify the path at the start of one of your scripts. None of the normal startup files will execute for a non-interactive session under Bash. Also try outputting `$SHELL` and make sure the script is running under the shell you think it is.

Comment: I'm using raspbian. I have tried your solution (edit /etc/environment) but the problem persist

Comment: That's odd. Did `/etc/environment/` already exist? It should on Raspbian. I wonder if something could be overwriting the path at a later point.

Comment: Make sure its just `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/scripts"`, and not `export PATH=...`; this is not a proper shell script.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote  `PATH="/usr/l...`

Comment: I have added `echo "$SHELL" | mail `mymail@gmail.com` to check the shell and I have recived a empty mail.